# How to comment on a comment

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have comment on a page and now I want it so that people can comment on a comment, So if Mr. X says "hello my name is X" I want Mr. Y to be able to comment to X and I want to have some kind of new database table called `under_reaction` or some kind. So I can display that comment under the first previous comment. I was wondering if someone can help me and give me advice on how to do this.

How it needs to look at the end:  [like this](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/nNm17)

This is the comment database table:

[image: The reaction database]

This code shows my comments:

```
if(isset($actieftopicid)){
                $reacttie = $app->get_reactie($actieftopicid);
                foreach ($reacttie as $reactie) {
echo '<li class="time-label">
                            <span class="bg-red">' .$reactie['datum'] .'</span>
                            </li>

                        <li><img class="img-circle reactieafbeelding" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/' . $reactie['klant_id'] . '/' . $reactie['foto'] . '" /><div class="timeline-item reactiewidth">
                                <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> ' .$reactie['tijd'] .'</span>  

                                <h3 class="timeline-header"><a href="#">' .$reactie['voornaam'] .' ' .$reactie['achternaam'] .'</a> ...</h3>  

                                <div class="timeline-body">
                                    '.$reactie['reactie']
                                .'</div>
                                <div class="timeline-footer">
                              <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i><a href="#reactie" style="color:black; margin-left: 2px;">Reageer</a></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>';
```

This gets the comments out of the database you can see here above, [image]  ^how it looks like,  Now I need to find some way to display the comments that are a comment to these comments

Comment: So you want a chat application then? This is waaaaaaaaaaaaaay too broad in scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is far too broad.  Please make some attempt to solve this yourself.  When you have some code written, if you are running into a _specific_ problem, feel free to come back and ask about that specific problem and provide the related code.

Comment: You can add a field parent_reaction that contains the id of the parent reaction, NULL otherwise. So when you open reaction #x, you can lookup for all the reactions that have parent_reaction=x to get the "sub reactions"

Comment: I am asking for help or tips how to do it, Because I already got that you can react on the page but now I need it so I can react to a reaction @PatrickQ

Comment: @CD001 look what I said in this comment above here

Comment: And we are more than happy to _help_, when you provide something for us to work with.  So far, all you've done is given a project spec.  Describe and show what you've done, what's working and what isn't, in detail, and then maybe we'll be able to help.  As has already been noted though, as it stands, this is far too broad.

Comment: I think all he is asking is how to create a hierarchy in SQL...

Comment: @PatrickQ gave you some more info

Comment: The OP wants to know how to store and read/render comments on comments. So a SO answer would be the main comment, the comments under the answer would be the 'sub comments'.

I would go with @YannP his suggestion to add a database column called `parent_reaction` to store the `id` of the main comment. For main comments this field would be `NULL`

Comment: @Brainfeeder But how am I showing the sub reactions? how do I link it that you know which reaction needs to go with which parent_reaction?

Comment: A good tip: Don't mix Dutch and English names in database fields/tables and in code. This will only cause chaos :) choose one and stick with it. Google can help you translate some stuff If you don't know some words.

Comment: @Brainfeeder well I am asking it in english so I thought I would make it as clear as possible for you

Comment: @thattommm Not talking about the text in the question, but about the names in your database and in your script.

Comment: ah okay well ill change it later when I fixed it all. but as I said: But how am I showing the sub reactions? how do I link it that you know which reaction needs to go with which parent_reaction?

Comment: To get the subreactions of a reaction that has id x, just SELECT * FROM reaction WHERE parent_id=x.

Comment: If you hard code it it will not work for everything??@YannP

Comment: @thattommm don't panic.. I'm guessing you are still a student or something? Am I right? (don't be offended if you aren't though) I added an answer, don't know if it clears things up for you?

Comment: @Brainfeeder I am not offended, I am happy someone is willing to help me with this. And yes I am a student trying to learn some things. and btw I commented on the question

Answer (score 0):

Run this script in `phpMyAdmin`:

```
ALTER TABLE `reacties` ADD `reactie_op` INT(11) DEFAULT(NULL);
```

The created column (field) will be used to store the id of the main comment (the comment where the newly added comment is a comment to)

```
$reacttie = $app->get_reactie($actieftopicid);
foreach ($reacttie as $reactie) {
    // Render main comment here

    // Then do new query for 'sub' comments
    $sub_reacttie = $app->get_sub_reactie($reactie['id']);
    foreach ($sub_reacttie as $sub_reactie) {
         // Render sub comment here
    }
}
```

Ideal would be that the first `get_reactie()` includes all sub comments in one call. But I don't know which platform you are using and how your model looks like etc, etc, ... It is kind of a huge question you asked and it would be better to try and solve this step by step.

The info I provided should get you on your way in solving this.

**edit**

The `get_sub_reactie()` function would be like this:

```
public function get_sub_reactie($main_reactie_id) {
    // get from database and use the $main_reactie_id in your query
    // so it only selects the rows from database where reactie_op = $main_reactie_id
}
```

Comment: before I can use this code: `$sub_reacttie = $app->get_sub_reactie($reactie['id']);` I need to make a function for that? don't I? And I am using a PDO

Comment: Yes, in the file where the `get_reactie()` function is you should make this new function. Most of the function will be the same. Only difference is you'll need to select `WHERE reactie_op = $id` (where `$id` is the value from `$reactie['id']` in the code in my answer.

Comment: So I need to do something like this ` $id= $reactie['id'];` too?

Comment: I updated my answer for you. I think you are trying stuff that is a little to difficult to understand at this point since these are basic things. Start with learning how an MVC works. If you get that, you'll find all this less complicated.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me! But I still got a little question, If I click on the 'reactie' button how will it set the right id from the main_reactie_id?

Comment: That depends on how your HTML is set up. If each main comment has a comment section with an input/textarea just make sure you post the id from the main comment with the new comment to the server instead of the new comment only. It is hard for us to know how you should do this in your case without all the files. You might be beter of posting a new question about 'how to post sub comment to database' or something.

Comment: or edit your question so it includes the code you use for saving a main comment. Slightly changing that could be enough.

Comment: I got 1 reaction field for the whole page so it needs to be set it some how.

Comment: That would be no good.. add form for each main comment.That will make things less complicated.

Comment: well I think ill do what you recommend then and do it after each reaction